# How do I make a bullet point list left-align, but be indented depending on the screen width?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I essentially want to do the following:

```
<h2 style="width:70%">
    <ul>
       <li>  Hi </li>
    </ul>
 </h2>
```

Unfortunately, the bullet point does not shift to 70% of the screen width. If I use the  tag outside then it does as follows, however then the content of the bullet point remains centered as well. I want it left aligned. Thanks!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post your code, please, so we can debug it? Also, welcome to SO and thanks for posting a legible and intellectual question.

Comment: @MaxTheG code was hidden in the question due to not being in coding format. Is now visible :)

Comment: Thanks for the welcoming, and thanks for who fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set a width for the `<ul>` element, but as well as a width, witch by default sets the contents centred, is to define the left or right margin as the remaining percentage.

```
.did {
    max-width:70%;
    margin-right:30%; /* 70+30 = 100 */
    border:#54F 1px solid; /* for display only. */
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class='did'>
<li>hi</li>
</ul>
```

Please view my jsFiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/2qxg47pa/2/

If you want your margin on the opposite side just change the rule. If you want it centred then set margin to auto.

Answer (score 0):

By using pseudo elements, you can achieve this:

```
h2 ul {
    width:70%;
    background-color:#666666;

}

div ul {
 width:70%;
    background-color:#666666;
    list-style-type:none;
}
div ul li {
    position:relative;
}
div ul li:before {
content:"•";
    position:absolute;
    left:-20px;

}
```

Code is for comparison... Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh7scf6a/1/
Resize window to see desired effect, of course. And, yes, works when ul is outside div, too... http://jsfiddle.net/gh7scf6a/3/

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to use the margin property.

```
h2 {margin: 30%;}
    <ul>
       <li>  Hi </li>
    </ul>
 </h2>
```

Shifting by 30% will put your text 30% shifted from the left side of the screen. Play with that number for desired results